# how i can fetch BNB price from pancakeswap in smart contract?

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, remix

I need help please!
how i can  fetch BNB
price from pancakeswap pool to my smart contract ?
and exchange BNB to WBNB with pancakeswap in solidity?.
** i need Please code exmaple**

Answer (score 1):

The live contract is available at https://github.com/shivapendem/dexpricecontract/blob/main/contract.sol
change the contract based on main net or testnet.

I added a reference where you can change the contract based on the currency as well